# AWS SSM check in ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to get a list of ec2 instances with no SSM installed.

I tried using boto3.describe_instance_information but getting an error.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.describe_instance_information

Below is my code

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client('ssm')


response = client.describe_instance_information(
    InstanceInformationFilterList=[
        {
            'key': 'i-0187655667fghj',
            'valueSet': [
                'AgentVersion',
                'InstanceIds'
            ]
        }
    ]
)


print(response)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssm.py", line 13, in <module>
    'InstanceIds'
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeInstanceInformation operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'i-0187655667fghj' at 'instanceInformationFilterList.1.member.key' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [ActivationIds, InstanceIds, PingStatus, PlatformTypes, ResourceType, IamRole, AssociationStatus, AgentVersion]
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the documentation properly? As it accepts the Instance ID.

```
{
            'key': 'InstanceIds'|'AgentVersion'|'PingStatus'|'PlatformTypes'|'ActivationIds'|'IamRole'|'ResourceType'|'AssociationStatus',
            'valueSet': [
                'string',
            ]
        }
```

so you have to pass ID

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client('ssm')


response = client.describe_instance_information(
    InstanceInformationFilterList=[
        {
            'key': 'InstanceIds',
            'valueSet': [
                'i-0187655667fghj'
            ]
        }
    ]
)


print(response)
```

**InstanceInformationFilterList**

> This is a legacy method. We recommend that you don't use this method.
>   Instead, use the InstanceInformationFilter action. The
>   InstanceInformationFilter action enables you to return instance
>   information by using tags that are specified as a key-value mapping.
>
> If you do use this method, then you can't use the
>   InstanceInformationFilter action. Using this method and the
>   InstanceInformationFilter action causes an exception error.

```
Type: Array of InstanceInformationFilter objects

Array Members: Minimum number of 0 items.

Required: No
```